# Tags added when improving an edit become unremovable

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Edit button shows source of older revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140973/edit-button-shows-source-of-older-revision)

The question [Linq to NHibernate - Incorrect SQL syntax from string Contains and StartsWith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629320/linq-to-nhibernate-incorrect-sql-syntax-from-string-contains-and-startswith) seems to have a tag that both exists and does not exist: [fffrgt](/questions/tagged/fffrgt).

Viewing the tag question list shows the question.  Viewing the question shows the tag in both the bottom and left tag list.

When clicking the edit tags link (or invoking the full question editor), [fffrgt](/questions/tagged/fffrgt) is missing, but saving does not remove it from the question.

What's going on here?  What is this tag, how did it appear, and why is it untouchable?

Comment: Huh, I can repro this

Comment: Verified, with a little bit of a twist.  When I edit tags, `fffrgt` is missing.  When I edit the entire post, `fffrgt` is there, and I remove it, save it, but it doesn't actually go away.

Comment: The tag was added as an "improvement" to a suggested edit. Should see if the same thing happens here...

Comment: I can see the tag in the tag list when editing...but my edit does not get saved. :(

Comment: [Reproduced on another question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7699479/revisions) by adding tags while improving an edit that added tags. (I approved by going directly to the post and selecting edit, so this bug isn't related to the review queues.)

Comment: Sorry to break your example, but I had to roll that nonsense back. Seems to be a [general issue with improved suggested edits](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1032809#1032809), though?

Comment: Marc did it! He replaced it with [tag:untagged]...but his edit is now gone...this is like watching Pulp Fiction!

Comment: I've updated the question title to reflect the cause of the problem.  Good investigation, folks.