# Edit button shows source of older revision

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor, edits

When I hit "edit" on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629021/delete-invisible-directory-after-a-git-clone) the editor shows the source not of the [current revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/11629021/3), but [the one before it](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/11629021/2).

I can reproduce this in multiple browsers, both logged in and anonymously and another user [confirmed it in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1032821#1032821).

I found it originally via the new review queue, that much I'm certain of. I thought I'd backed out of an improve in the new review queue on this one and done it from the question page itself in the end, after it had already been approved but the timestamps in the revision history and the log on the [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/327339) disagree there so I might be misremembering that.

Comment: This is [supposed to have been fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140020/after-improving-an-edit-question-shows-new-version-edit-shows-old-version) but apparently it is not.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I thought I remembered something recently, but search turned up nothing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [This question seems to have an unremovable tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140972/this-question-seems-to-have-an-unremovable-tag)

Comment: Some more findings in the comments at [Suggested edit comes after the improved one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140233/suggested-edit-comes-after-the-improved-one/140240#140240).

Comment: I MESSED THIS UP, but in my defense coding is more fun drunk

Comment: http://twitter.com/kevinmontrose/statuses/227822660053262336

Comment: @GeoffDalgas [I think you missed a status-completed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140972/tags-added-when-improving-an-edit-become-unremovable).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was a fun one to track down - it turned out to be a case where ordering revisions based only on creation date was somewhat of a bad idea.  It only presented itself on a SQL instance with a high volume of inserts combined with a change that we made to sync up all post creation dates for an action such as improving a suggested edit which approves the existing suggested edit and inserts an additional edit all using the same exact date and time.

Comment: I'm not sure it is fixed. For the post discussed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141121/edit-blocked-because-it-must-be-more-substantive-than-an-approved-2-hour-old-edi), when I click the edit link on the post, I get the same "must be more substantial" notification and my edits are rejected (haven't tried a complete rewrite, perhaps that'd count as more substantial;). From the [revisions page](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11648979/revisions), I get the same source (rev 2) when clicking the edit link of either rev 2 or rev 3, and get a warning that I edit an old revision.

Comment: However, anonymously suggesting [an edit](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/329490) worked. What are the differences between the "improve this question" link for anonymous users and the edit link for logged-in users that one works but not the other?