# Edit blocked because it must be more substantive than an approved 2 hour old edit

Tags: bug, edits

Having been alerted to some [edits that were not entirely helpful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141089/if-it-is-in-italic-it-must-be-pretty) by Meta this morning, I decided to go through and fix up what I could. However, I find that I'm unable to provide an edit (albeit a fairly minor one) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648979/parsing-environment-variables-as-arguments-in-jnlp-file). When clicking <kbd>Save Edits</kbd> I'm prompted with the following:

[image: Edit must be more substantive]

My understanding is that this is the error message that should appear if two editors create overlapping revisions that clash in some way. In this case, though Jesse Rusak *did* in fact provide an edit, it took place over **2 hours ago**:

[image]

It seems to me that I should be able to edit the latest revision, as created by Jesse Rusak, without receiving this message. My only suspicion here is that [the suggested edit originally provided](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/328934) was improved, and perhaps that somehow messed up the revision history.

I tried hard refreshing the question and re-submitting the edit but the problem persisted. I'm using the latest stable Chrome (20.whatever) on Windows 7. Is this a bug, or am I doing something horribly wrong?

Comment: I wonder if this was related to [Edit button shows source of older revision](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140973/edit-button-shows-source-of-older-revision).

Comment: @PopularDemand: I'm not sure. It *appears* to show the most recent revision when I hit the `edit` link, but they certainly could be related issues.