# I cannot edit a post after I improved a suggested edit

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits

I have improved a suggested edit for https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38050/drupal-registration-testing-with-jmeter on Drupal Answers, and I have noticed that I wrote a word swapping two letters. I am trying to edit it to fix that typo, but all the times I try I get the following message:

> digital already edited the body of this post; your edit must be more substantive to override the current edit.

[image: screenshot]

I was the [last one who edited that post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/38050/revisions).

The revision on Drupal Answers is 2012.7.24.3467.

I also notice another issue: If I go to the revision page, and I click on the edit link for my revision, what I get is not my revision.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Furthermore, if I go to the [timeline page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/38050/timeline) for that question, and I click on the "show revision" links, this is what I get.

[image: screenshot]

The first link doesn't work.

Using the Web Inspector, this is the HTML for that link, and the tags including it.

```
<div style="padding:5px; width:700px">
  <div class="unexpanded-revision rev-div-id-rev-380502012-07-25-03-19 rev-guids-690d1cc6-ffc4-478f-8f8f-1aa227a7ec13_690d1cc6-ffc4-478f-8f8f-1aa227a7ec13_eb742b85-44e1-48cc-8d30-ff6bd135cf56 rev-post-id-38050" id="rev-380502012-07-25-03-19"><a onclick="showRevision('rev-380502012-07-25-03-19', 38050, '690d1cc6-ffc4-478f-8f8f-1aa227a7ec13_690d1cc6-ffc4-478f-8f8f-1aa227a7ec13_eb742b85-44e1-48cc-8d30-ff6bd135cf56', false, null)"><span class="show-rev">show revision</span></a></div>
  <table style="margin-left:15px">
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Potentially related to [Edit blocked because it must be more substantive than an approved 2 hour old edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141121/edit-blocked-because-it-must-be-more-substantive-than-an-approved-2-hour-old-edi#comment399128_141121) and/or [Edit button shows source of older revision](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140973/edit-button-shows-source-of-older-revision), which were both asked very recently.

Comment: Timeline confirms http://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/38050/timeline (and interestingly enough I can't click "show revision" on digital's post)

Comment: @sixlettervariables I cannot do that either. If I click, the revision is not shown.

Comment: I could just submit an anonymous suggested edit for that question, so that seems to work.

Comment: @DanielFischer And also editing after the suggested edit worked.

Comment: Okay, together with [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141121/edit-blocked-because-it-must-be-more-substantive-than-an-approved-2-hour-old-edi), I'd say we established that improving suggested edits breaks something. Oddly, anonymous suggested edits work, but not editing by logged-in users.