# Can a user gain more than 2 rep for editing?

Tags: bug, status-planned, reputation, suggested-edits

I edited [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3023085) and noticed my reputation change from **1466** to **1470** (i.e +4). I went to check my reputation changes and found:

> [image: 4 rep]

**Note:** My reputation later went down from **1470** to **1468**, so it appears the system realized it made a mistake and corrected my reputation, but hasn't gotten rid of the second revision or the history event.

My [activity history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2509901/precioustijesunimi?tab=activity) still shows **1** suggested edit with **2** revisions.

Comment: Strange [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19067232/revisions), on that post, has two revs. from you pointing to the same edit suggestion.

Comment: @Mat Wow. Never noticed that. But i didn't make two edits??

Comment: Both revisions point to the same [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/918576).  Seems like a bug!

Comment: @devnull Yes and my [Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2509901/precioustijesunimi?tab=activity) Shows one **suggested edit** and two **revisions**

Comment: Looks like it might be a regression/related to [an old edit timestamp bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140999/153020).

Comment: @Flexo: But animuson said [*I assure you that's not at all related.*.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/198698/revisions).

Comment: This bug has [occured again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216355/four-points-for-editing?lq=1)

Comment: ...and [again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226977/168244)...

Comment: ... and again [one more time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228216/total-increased-reputation-is-incorrect)

Comment: Don't fix it while I'm showering in my illegally gained rep… (bug happened to me twice)

Comment: [And again!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265677/how-come-i-got-4-rep-points-for-a-single-post-edit)

Answer (score 20):

There is definitely something strange going on.

First, the time stamps on the edits are different:

- Revision 2 was approved at 13:24:57Z
- Revision 3 was approved at 13:24:58Z

Those timestamps match the +2 entries in your profile.

But when you look at the reviewer timestamps is when things get screwy:

- talonmies approved the edit at 13:21:30Z
- us2012 approved the edit at 13:24:57Z
- Parado approved the edit at 13:24:58Z (which was 1 second after Revision 2 was approved).

If the timestamps can be trusted, it appears that something happened that allowed 2 approvals to approve the edit, but at then also approved the edit with the 3rd approval.

Answer (score 13):

Nope. It isn't (well, *shouldn't* be) possible to gain more than 2 points for making a single edit.

As Mat pointed out in the comments, the edit revisions history does look weird.

This could be a bug, but I'm not exactly sure what's causing this.

Comment: Both link to the same suggested edit though, something's wrong here.

Comment: @Mat Yes and also in my [Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2509901/precioustijesunimi?tab=activity) It shows one edit suggestion and two Revisions

Comment: @Mat: You're right. Something's wrong.

Comment: Is it possible that two people reviewed the edit at the same time, both improved it and marked that the suggestion was helpful?

Comment: @jmac: when an edit is "improved" it is visible in the post history: you get one entry for the suggested edit (as suggested) and a second one for the "improvement", associated with the reviewer.

Comment: @jmac Nice guess, but if you click through to the revision history you can see that nobody improved this suggestion.

Comment: Then two people just accepted it as-is? Or clicked improve and changed nothing?

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi please don't mark this accepted. Bug report should be "closed" only when it's being either fixed or rejected by a dev.

Comment: I agree with @ShaWizDowArd here. You can untick the checkmark and wait for a moderator/developer to respond to the question.

Answer (score 8):

After a ton of digging through the database trying to identify how many users hit this bug and the cause of it, we've determined that it's a race condition.

The fix will be going in this week, once we've identified all the places where we're hitting this same issue (Shog's got a list). The fix will include a redis lock (which we already use elsewhere), and it will prevent these very rare multiple entries.

As far as the rep from these aka the extra +2, there are very few cases in which this happened and it involves deleting from several tables to clean it up, so we're leaving it. It shouldn't happen again after this week, when the bug is fixed.