# Reputation increases by 4 instead of 2

Tags: bug, reputation, edits, suggested-edits

I made several edit suggestions and each time my reputation increased by 2, except once when it increased by 4 (cool! :D) . But my reputation increased only by 2 (less cool ;) ).

> [image]

I think there is a bug when I received +4 instead of +2.

Comment: Apparently your suggestion counted twice: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22659563/revisions

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much! I went too fast in my edit.
But there is still a bug, it would have to count me once, isn't it? (in the +4 displayed)

Comment: Yes, to me it is a bug because the suggestion id is the same: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4439034 so you should get +2 instead of 2 x +2

Comment: Thank's very much for your attention. :)

Comment: [This has happened before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198697/can-a-user-gain-more-than-2-rep-for-editing), but I'm reluctant to close as a duplicate yet as I don't want this to get buried in old bug reports

Comment: Another reason not to close as a duplicate is I am not convinced it is the same issue.  The previous issue I linked might not be the exact same issue as the earlier post had 2 different timestamps for the 2 revisions, whereas yours have the same timestamp.  It is still related and I added a bounty to the other question to get some more visibility.

Comment: Looks like a "free rep bug for 1 out of 1000000 edits" - enjoy it while you can!

Comment: @S.L. Barth was it by mis-click ?

Comment: @Kedarnath No, I felt you left too much unattended in your edit suggestion.

Comment: @Kedarnath Er, I did change several things to your edit suggestion. You left "several edit" in singular, and left "reputation increased 2" and "reputation increased 4". I added the "by" there. Off the top of my head, I think I changed a few other things as well.